# How do i delete item from local storage with delegation?

Tags: javascript, html

I m trying to make a bookmark app in which when i type the name and address of a website they should appear  underneath the form when i click submit button.Also when i click the delete button it should remove item not only from UI but also from local storage.And that s the problem.I have no problem deleting them from UI but when i reload the page they keep showing up.I know it s complicated but if someone s interested i would urge them to pay attention to Store class which deals with storage particulary deleteBookmarkFromStorage() method.

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", saveBookmark);

document.querySelector(".col-lg-12").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const ui = new UI();
  ui.deleteItem(e.target);
  Store.deleteBookmarkFromStorage(e.target.parentElement);
  ui.showAlert("You deleted a bookmark", "alert alert-success");
  e.preventDefault();
});

class Bookmark {
  constructor(siteName, siteUrl) {
    this.siteName = siteName;
    this.siteUrl = siteUrl;
  }
}

class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.siteName = document.getElementById("siteName");
    this.siteUrl = document.getElementById("siteUrl");
    this.bookmarksResults = document.getElementById("bookmarksResults");
  }

  showAlert(message, className) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    div.className = className;
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    const bookmarkCard = document.getElementById("bookmarkCard");
    container.insertBefore(div, bookmarkCard);

    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector(".alert").remove();
    }, 3000);
  }

  showBookmark(bookmark) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "card-body";
    div.innerHTML = `
    <h3 class="inline-block">${bookmark.siteName}</h3>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" 
    href=${bookmark.siteUrl}>Visit</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a>
    
     `;
    const results = this.bookmarksResults;
    results.appendChild(div);
  }

  clearInput() {
    this.siteName.value = "";
    this.siteUrl.value = "";
  }

  deleteItem(target) {
    if (target.className === "btn btn-danger") {
      target.parentElement.remove();
    }
  }
}

class Store {
  static getBookmarks() {
    let bookmarks;
    if (localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") === null) {
      bookmarks = [];
    } else {
      bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));
    }
    return bookmarks;
  }

//show bookmarks in UI
  static displayBookmarks() {
    const bookmarks = Store.getBookmarks();
    bookmarks.forEach(function(bookmark) {
      const ui = new UI();

      ui.showBookmark(bookmark);
    });
  }

//Add bookmark to storage
  static addBookmarkToStorage(bookmark) {
    const bookmarks = Store.getBookmarks();

    bookmarks.push(bookmark);
    localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  }

  //Delete bookmark from storage
  static deleteBookmarkFromStorage() {
    const bookmarks = Store.getBookmarks();

    bookmarks.forEach(function(bookmark) {
      if (bookmark.className === "btn btn-danger") {
        bookmarks.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
    localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", Store.displayBookmarks);

function saveBookmark(e) {
  const siteName = document.getElementById("siteName").value;
  const siteUrl = document.getElementById("siteUrl").value;

  const bookmark = new Bookmark(siteName, siteUrl);
  const ui = new UI();

  if (siteName === "" || siteUrl === "") {
    ui.showAlert("Please fill in all the fields", "alert alert-danger");
  } else {
    ui.showBookmark(bookmark);
    Store.addBookmarkToStorage(bookmark);
    ui.showAlert("You added a new bookmark", "alert alert-success");
    ui.clearInput();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>My JavaScript App</title>
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h3 class="mt-3 mb-3 text-muted">Bookmarker</h3>
      <hr />
      <div class="card card-body pt-5 pb-5 mb-3" id="bookmarkCard">
        <h2>Bookmark Your Favorite Sites</h2>
        <form id="myForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Site Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="siteName"
              placeholder="Website Name"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Site URL</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="siteUrl"
              placeholder="Website URL"
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " id="submitButton">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div id="bookmarksResults"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2019 Bookmarker, Inc.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="build/app.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ahdr.jpg)eteBookmarkFromStorage() method.

Comment: Did you consider using sessionStorage instead of localStorage? localStorage stores the values in the Browser forever, sessionStorage only for one session.

Comment: Tom, did you mean forever is until the browser clean up it cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove everything from the local storage before writing back the updated object:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Also, check out how it would work with `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```js
//event listener
 Store.deleteBookmarkFromStorage( e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.textContent
  );
  
  //Class Store
  static deleteBookmarkFromStorage(siteName) {
    const bookmarks = Store.getBookmarks();

    bookmarks.forEach(function(bookmark, index) {
      if (bookmark.siteName === siteName) {
        bookmarks.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
    localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  }
```